# Cannot pass any options to \arrow in TikZ-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Whenever I use the `\arrow` command of the `tikzcd` package, I receive a compilation error, if I try to pass any additional options apart from the direction.
This happens only on a machine with a TeXlive installation.
On another machine with MikTeX installation, all of the following examples compile just fine.

Example 1: Does compile.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar{r} & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Example 2: Does not compile. No error message. Only log message: "[LaTeX] ended with return value 1."

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Example 3: Does not compile. No error message. Only log message: "[LaTeX] ended with return value 1."

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar{r,"f"} & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Example 4: Does not compile. No error message. Only log message: "[LaTeX] ended with return value 1."

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[r,"f"] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to fix it?
Sadly I do not have admin rights for this machine, so it would be best to have a fix which does not require admin rights.
However if I tell the admin very clearly what is the problem, he may be able to do something for me, but all sorts of fiddling around and ggathering additional info (like what version of texlive is installed) is out of the question.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Though I have not used tikz-cd library personally.  But your second example compiles, if you change {} to [] before \ar.  First and third one are compiling perfectly without any changes.

Comment: You will have to compare the versions of your packages. Add `\listfiles` to your preamble, compile, and search your `.log` for the package `tikz-cd`. For sure, you will notice some difference here. The solution would be: Update the older system. Btw.: Example 3 looks rather wrong to me. But I will update my system before judging on this.

Comment: Ok, I am using the `tikz-cd` version `2014/10/30 v0.9e Commutative diagrams with tikz` and everything works fine but the third example. This one should most probably be `A \ar{r}{f}`. Please tell me where you found this syntax. As you cannot find the version of your tool nor change your system, the only fix would be to find one (out of many) approach which works and use it of every arrow.

Comment: I did not found the syntax `\ar{r,"f"}` anywhere. I was just making a guess. `\ar{r}{f}` works for me, so thank you very much for that suggestion!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Do you happen to know where I can find a documentation of this syntax? I want to pass on other parameters to my arrows, such as `'` or `dashrightarrow`.

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf (PDF download)

Comment: Following your link I receive a 404 not found error. However I assume it is the same document as http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf . My desired information is found in section 1.4 - a part that I had overlooked previously. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for arrows is described in sections 1.2 and 1.4 of the manual which can be found on your system by typing `texdoc tikz-cd` in your command prompt.

Comment: As commented above: The alternative syntax mentioned ins section 1.4 works for me. That is `\arrow{r}{label}`. Thanks!